# dialog- button text

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$("#modal").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function () {
            alert("Cancel");
        },
        Add user: function () {
                alert("Add user");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my code for a modal pop up. i have 2 button Cancel and  Add user
.but "Add user"  gives error for me. if it is Add_user it is ok. 
what work around can i have, to have Add user as a  text on my button
?

Comment: "Add user" gives what error? That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties need to be quoted. Put "Add user" into quotes.

```
buttons: {
    "Cancel": function () {
        alert("Cancel");
    },
    "Add user": function () {
        alert("Add user");
    }
}
```

Without the quotes you will see a Javascript error which should make the mistake clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons: {
    "<%=resourceManager.GetGlobalResourceObject("Text_Cancel_Camel")%>": function () {
        alert(".............")
    },
    "<%=resourceManager.GetGlobalResourceObject("Text_Add_User")%>": function () {
            alert(".............")
    }
}
```